# Laravel add multiple classes when using Form::open()

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Currently I have a form that looks like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'lists.store', 'class' => 'form1']) !!}
```

I was wondering how can I add multiple classes something like the following

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'lists.store', 'class' => 'form', 'blah', 'blah2']) !!}
```

I am expecting the result to be:

```
<form class="form blah blah2" ...
```

but instead i just get an error.

Comment: @Abdulla hahahaha yep that did it thanks, make it an answer, I'll accept

Comment: What's this stuff `{!!`, what template engine, it's ugly.  Just imagine doing this `<jet:form action="{$route}lists.store" class="form, blah, blah2 ></jet:form>`  @o@

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix its blade templating syntax used in Laravel. kind of like handlebars.js

Comment: Sorry, I don't like it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just Try this

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'lists.store', 'class' => 'form blah blah2']) !!}
```

Comment: What did you change, I have no knowledge of blade templates? Just curious can you explain with a sentence or 2?

Comment: Classes can be added without using a comma to separate them.  So 'class' => 'form', 'blah', 'blah2' became 'class' => 'form blah blah2'